# C++ exception class extension syntax

Tags: c++

I am taking a course online and came across some syntax I am not really sure I understand.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <exception>

    using namespace std;

    class derivedexception: public exception {
          virtual const char* what() const throw() {
            return "My derived exception";
  }        
    } myderivedexception;

    int main() {
          try {
            throw myderivedexception;
          }
          catch (exception& e) {
            cout << e.what() << '\n';
          }
    }
```

My Problem is with:

```
    virtual const char* what() const throw()
```

What does this line mean?

also, what is with the

```
    } myderivedexception;
```

in the end of the class declaration?

Comment: Please have a look at this [C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) list.

Comment: You'd probably be much better served reading a [C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/241631) for beginners. If this course is showing you the code above without first introducing you to inheritance and virtual functions, it doesn't sound like a good course.

Comment: Not catching the exception by `const&` is also strange. What are you going to do with that non-const reference? Modify the exception after it's been caught? That doesn't make sense. Neither does creating the `myderivedexception` object. Forget about this course.

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
  virtual const char* what() const throw()
```

says that `what` is a virtual method that returns a pointer to a constant `char` (which means it can be used to return a string literal, or the contents of a std::string obtained by calling the string::c_str() function), is itself constant so it doesn't modify any class members, and it does not throw any exceptions.

This line:

```
   } myderivedexception;
```

creates an instance of the `derivedexception` class named `myderivedexception`. You probably do not want to do this, but instead throw an unnamed exception:

```
throw derivedexception();
```

Comment: Got a question about the `virtual`. Is it really needed? Isn't this already the override for the `what` method contained within `std::exception `?

Comment: No, it's not needed, using it this situation is really a question of style - some people like it.

Comment: Ok, so the throw() part means that it does not throw any exceptions? Is there any depth on this?

Could you initiate an object in the end of the class declaration as a "default" object?

Comment: "Ok, so the throw() part means that it does not throw any exceptions? " - yes.Why would you want a "default object"?

Comment: Tbh, I don't, the lecturer for some weird reason decided to, plus he did not even care to explain why